# Bad encoding Spark dataframe when load data from Ignite 2.8 (as database)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ignite

I use Spark 2.4 and Ignite 2.8 on Windows 10

When I put pyspark dataframe to ignite table it saved well.

But, when I read this data back from Ignite to Pyspark dataframe is back in system default encoding (CP1251). I don't understand how get correct data with correct encoding back.

This is example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark
import os

# Starting local SPARK
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = " --driver-memory 18g --executor-memory 20g --jars ///C:/Ignite/libs/*.jar,///C:/Ignite/libs/optional/ignite-spark-2.4/*.jar,///C:/Ignite/libs/ignite-spring/*.jar,///C:/Ignite/libs/ignite-indexing/*.jar pyspark-shell"
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('testIgnite').setMaster('local[2]')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
sqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)
configFile = "c:/ignite/examples/config/my-data-regions.xml"

# Create test pandas dataframe
ndf=pd.DataFrame([[0,'Тест1'],
                  [1,'Другой Тест2']
                 ], columns=['c1','c2'])

# Create spark dataframe from pandas df
sdf=sqlContext.createDataFrame(ndf)
sdf.show() #Output 2

# save data to Ignite
sdf.write\
.format("ignite")\
.option("table",'TEST_TABLE_2')\
.option("primaryKeyFields", 'c1')\
.option("config",configFile)\
.mode("overwrite")\
.save()

# load data from Ignite
idf=sqlContext.read.format("ignite")\
.option("table",'TEST_TABLE_2')\
.option("config",configFile)\
.load()

idf.show() #Output 2

#stop Spark
sc.stop()
```

This output#1 - GOOD !

```
+---+------------+
| c1|          c2|
+---+------------+
|  0|       Тест1|
|  1|Другой Тест2|
+---+------------+
```

This output#2 - BAD ENCODE :(

```
+--------------------+---+
|                  C2| C1|
+--------------------+---+
|           РўРµСЃС‚1|  0|
|Р”СЂСѓРіРѕР№ РўРµ...|  1|
+--------------------+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend storing everything in UTF-8, using -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 JVM parameter.